# Migrating existing GWT project to new GWT version

Tags: maven, gwt, ant, migration, gxt

I have been in charge for the past 5 years of the development and the maintenance of a GWT project which consists of 6 different WebApps. The project is using GWT 1.5 and is built with ant (for either mode dev/war). These webapps are deployed on apache-tomcat, the production site run version 5.5 whereas we run (for testing) version 7.0.

To emphasize user experience, I would like to migrate the GWT version to a more recent one (of which I have no idea so far); I have read many things about migrating, regarding deprecated APIs, improvments made frome one version to another and I have still structural questions dealing with the new project layout itself.

Currently, the layout is the following:

```
WebXXX 
-src
 -net.yyy.webxxx
   -common
    -client
    -server
    -public
    -Common.gwt.xml
   -module1
    -client
    -server
    -public
    -module1.gwt.xml
   -[...]
-test
-build
 -build.xml
 -buildModule1.xml
 -[..]
-Dependencies(SVN_Externals)
-www
-compile-all-modules.xml
-compile-module1.xml
-WebXXXHosted.xml
-[..]
```

To explicit things a bit, the fodler Dependencies is a place-holder for linking Workspace sources with an external widgets library. This library is built at compile time (when building all modules or just one within an ant task) and the resulting jar is injected into the module WEB-INF/lib directory. That widget library does use gxt.1.1.1 and gwt-incubator 1.5.

Over the years, writing a new ant task for each new WebApp seemed to be the solution but now that we are also using maven, I am wondering if I must convert the project to a maven project before doing the migration or if I can skip, for now, the maven conversion.

Since I guess maven is not absolutely required and since the project includes several customized ant tasks to have it run (in dev mode), I am also wondering if I could (instead) migrate the related GWT jars in a version which is such that I won't have to rewrite all the UI though I know I will have major replacement to do and extensive tests to run.

Feel free to enlighten me about the way I could go (maven or not, the version of gwt I should migrate to, the related gxt version (if it's still relevant) to use) because I am in complete darkness !

Thanks for all,
Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Go one step at a time.

- **Always** use the latest version (and migrate ASAP when a new version comes out). That being said, there've been reports of 2.5 and 2.5.1 having a few regressions in GWT-RPC, so if it doesn't work, try using 2.4 (but try 2.5.1 first!)
- You'll have to update your GXT dependency too (I have no idea how they deal with backwards compatibility at Sencha and how much it will break your code –or not–; and again try to stay up-to-date)
- gwt-incubator is deprecated for long, so be prepared to replace some of the widgets, and in the long run you'll want to totally remove that dependency.
- don't move to Maven until after you upgraded GWT, unless upgrading breaks your Ant tasks too much (then try moving to Maven and then upgrading GWT; but 1.5 is a really old version so I have no idea how well it works with Maven).

Re. Maven, GWT will soon use Maven too and will provide an *official* plugin. Alpha versions of that plugin can be found at https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-plugin (I've received rather positive feedback for now); or you can use the gwt-maven-plugin from CodeHaus, or simply call the GWT Compiler with the exec-maven-plugin (or the antrun-maven-plugin). As for the project layout, see http://blog.ltgt.net/announcing-gwt-maven-archetypes-project, this is the layout the *official* GWT plugin will be based on (and again, mostly positive feedback so far).

Comment: GXT 1.1 is relatively ancient - I think GXT 2 was released shortly before GWT 1.6 and while it had a fairly small set of changes compared to GXT 1, version 3 made substantial changes. That said, the main backward compat issues will be in the JClassType class->interface transition in GWT 2.2, for this it may be necessary to recompile a few classes in the gxt 1.1 jar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to do both migrate to gwt and maven, I would face first to migrate the existing project to maven. You have to be sure that all dependencies are in maven repositories or you know how to deal with local repositories. Once you have everything mavenized in modules and you can import the projects in eclipse (maybe you need an old gwt plugin) and run all tasks I would try to migrate module by module selecting the appropriate dependencies.

I think updating dependencies with maven is pretty easier than dealing with ant, but of course you could select the other way if you feel more conifrtable.

Anyway, the task of migrating a gwt application from 1.5 to 2.5.1 could be hard. First you have to know how the evolution of gwt to know which issues could come to your app (new widgets interfaces, handlers, etc).

You are depending on gwt-incubator which has been discontinued since some years ago, maybe you have a build which could work with gwt-2.5.1, but probably there are many things which dont work any more. There are some features which have been moved from incubator to gwt like cell-lists, date-picker, etc, so you have to rewrite your code using new stuff in gwt.

Your project depends on an old gxt version, they have made many changes in theirs api, and I think you have to deal with a lot of changes in your code as well.

In summary, mavenizing an ant project is not so difficult and you have plenty of information in the web, but porting a gwt app from 1.5 to 2.5.1 is not a trivial task, if you dont have a good suite of tests it could be harder, so be prepared to spend a lot of time figuring out how to replace old things and to fix issues.